# How can I include the address in the letter text?

Tags: dinbrief

I want to include the address, as defined in

```
\address{My address here}
```

at a certain point in the text of the letter.

I am using `dinbrief` 1.73.

Comment: Welcome to tex.SE. "in the text of _the_ letter": what letter are you talking about? Please give a minimal working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to be able to use the text you add in the `\address` field somewhere else in the document formatted as entered, you can just add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\repeataddress}{\@fromaddress}
\makeatother
```

Then use `\repeataddress` where you want to reuse the address.

Comment: Advance congratulations for 100k. :) As I am irregular these days, I may miss the time. So in advance. Hurry up and hurray.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. Another day or so I guess.